# Python2.7 is officially deprecated, with support having ended on January 1, 2020. What now on Mac?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

`DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support`

For years, I was told not to uninstall Python 2.7 in favor of Python 3 because Mac OS and many applications use it. Now that Python 2.7 is deprecated, will Mac OS continue to use it? Should I uninstall it?

Comment: No, don't uninstall your system Python. You probably shouldn't even be touching it, use a separate installation, and maintain various versions using virtual environments

Comment: Your question sound like you have decide to use either 2 or 3. But you can easily install bother versions in parallel.

Comment: It looks like you are free to install the latest version of python [Based on the documentation provided by apple](https://docs.python.org/2/using/mac.html). I would use virtual environments to do this though, as to ensure you are not messing with anything internally.